# REST create subresources in the same transaction.(RESTEasy)

Tags: rest, resteasy, api-design

Consider the scenerio,
Have an Object called Device, device could have multiple parameters associated to it which could be of multiple types.

```
base-device-param (/xx/yy/4/base-device-param)
device-param-type1 extends base-resource-param (/xx/yy/{device-id}/device-param-type1) 
device-param-type2 extends base-resource-param (/xx/yy/{device-id}/device-param-type2)
```

With the RESTFul way of handling inheritence, the base type and each sub-type will have their own URI and their own schema (as mentioned above).

When I create a device, as you know, A POST operation will be made on /xx/yy.

At the time of creation, we have to associate the parameters to the device. Adding device parameters cant be a different transaction. These parametes are contained by the device and is not an association. so I cant create the parameters prior.

Should I go for RPC like approach or is there a strict REST way of handling this?

By the way, I use RESTEasy if case if you are going to suggest Batch operation.

Comment: Can the representation of the device *include* the to be created parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Include the parameters in the `device` representation.

```
<device>
  <id>d123</id>
  <!-- more device properties -->

  <parameters>
    <param>
      <key>foo</key>
      <value>bar</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>baz</key>
      <value>qux</value>
    </param>
    <!-- more parameters>
  </parameters>
</device>
```

Your REST resource will have to map this representation to Java classes. What you *do* with them, if and how you store them, is up to you.

Comment: I thought of the parameters appoach, but the drawback is, i will have to convert them from the orignial representation to map representation while querying. I didn't want to break the elegance of REST over there. Or is it acceptable to have <parameters> field in POST alone?

Comment: I think, I shall create a generic fragment called <options> common to all my rest resources. If custom options have to be passed as a part of the request, I pass it as a part of <options><option key value>*.. I know the recommended way is Query parametes.. But i think query parametes can't handle all the cases.